# Tweenlite background image to remain stable

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

I am curently having an issue with Tweenlite js with the background images.
So in this code i have set one map on the background and some points above it as different images but still in the background.
You can see it live here

```
http://socialextensions.eu/maptest/gigi/index.html
```

Now when i move the mouse all the images are floating left and right, but i want only the points to move and the map to remain stable.
Did some research but i had no luck.

Here is the code

***script inside html***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).mousemove(function(e){
    TweenLite.to($('body'), .5, { css: {
        backgroundPosition: "" + parseInt(event.pageX/8)    + "px " 
                               + parseInt(event.pageY/'12') + "px, "
                               + parseInt(event.pageX/'15') + "px " 
                               + parseInt(event.pageY/'15') + "px, "
                               + parseInt(event.pageX/'30') + "px "                       
                               + parseInt(event.pageY/'30') + "px"
      }
    });
  });
});
```

***css***

```
body
{
  background-color: #242424;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: url(../images/mapbg.jpg);
  background-color: #444;
  background: url(http://mymaplist.com/img/parallax/pinlayer2.png),url(http://mymaplist.com/img/parallax/pinlayer1.png),url(../images/mapbg.jpg);  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Anyone has any idea?

I've already tried to change the  `.5`  which you can see at the js code also the  `parseInt(event.pageX/8)` but it only made slow movement.

Also tried to put css to the spesific url image like this

```
body
{
  background-color: #242424;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: url(../images/mapbg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-color: #444;
  background: url(http://mymaplist.com/img/parallax/pinlayer2.png),url(http://mymaplist.com/img/parallax/pinlayer1.png),url(../images/mapbg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: I think this is because you have all the images applied on the same `body` element as `background` images. In order to create the parallax effect that you seemed to be after, you need to create separate layers for each of the `background` images and then target only the one that you want to animate on `mousemove`.